# All in one car seat and pushchair that lasts up to 4 years

Tags: toddler, infant, newborn, age-appropriate, car-seat

I'm looking for a pushchair that has just one seat, but that seat can be used:

1) As a car seat up to 4 years old

2) Taken and put into the pushchair

3) Also has a handle that I can use to carry the baby when I walk

It appears most pushchairs come with just a separate car seat that only lasts till about 12 months, is there such thing as a car seat that will last a long time as well as work in a pushchair?

Comment: Posting as a comment bc this is not an answer. I think that you will not find the option you are looking for bc after 12 months, the weight of the child plus the chair increases to the point where the amount of effort required to lift it cancels out the convenience of avoiding unbuckling/buckling.

Comment: I second Jax's comment. I don't think they're able to engineer a car seat that is suitable for infants through 4 years, and is detachable for use in a stroller. Yes, it's physically possible to make such a device, but I don't think it would meet regulatory safety criteria.

Comment: Almost seems like an academic challenge.  A cross between a child's seat (a pushchair?) and a wheelchair.  Side note: age is not as relevant as weight when it comes to safety seats. Personal Commentary: The "sling" was **awesome!**

Comment: But I have seen some dedicated car seats that have inner expanding/removable parts that make the seat bigger as the baby grows (for example http://www.joiebaby.com/car-seats). But just can't find these in a pushchair, I think its a industry tactic more than anything to make you buy.

Comment: Push chair = stroller, I believe.

Comment: Is this your first kid? You'd be surprised at the number of things you don't need. First time around everyone wants to be prepared, and all these fancy things look like a sane choice. Several years later, after you realize the stroller that came with a detachable car seat is way too cumbersome and impossible to wrestle into the trunk, you realize how many of the all in one solutions are unnecessary, burdensome, or extremely filthy by the time they're ready to be used for their other purposes. I'd get a good car seat and a $25 small collapsible stroller

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [sit n stroll](http://www.lillygold.com/products/sit-n-stroll.html) I've never used one but it seems to fit your criteria. Not promoting this particular brand, but it appears to be at least a good starting point for a search of comparable items.

I had the three in one system for my oldest child, but did not reuse it when I had my second and third. I think I do remember seeing the sit n stroll or something similar when I was shopping for my registry, and I'm pretty sure I passed on it due to the weight issue, and I knew I wouldn't be traveling.

I found having a good quality infant/toddler/booster seat plus a nimble, compact stroller (one that can be opened/folded with one hand is ideal) to be the most convenient and economical in my experience as a working mother of three boys. That's just my two cents.

Happy converting!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you will find a car seat that lasts up to 4 years and can be put onto the wheels...

But we bought the Cosatto Giggle Travel System and it is fantastic.
The buggy comes with a bassinet, a puschair and you can also get the Cosatto Hold seat and adapters which go on the wheels.

Its not that expensive and the seat is meant to last until 12 months.
Its so handy when baby is asleep and you can move from car onto wheels easily. It has padding which you can take out to make the space bigger, my little one is 6 months and we have only just taken it out.

Hope that helps.